# Microsoft Office Word Error

Tags: microsoft-word, microsoft-word-2010

I had a problem with showing some pages in Word 2010 (as following image). It has never happen before. I tried many ways to fix but i couldn't. Please help!

[image: IMG:]

Comment: does that happen when you copy paste the texts?

Answer (score 0):

May be a ruler error, try changing the length of the page on the left of the screen, or closing the ruler feature.

Answer (score 0):

I've never used Web View, but your display looks a little bit like you have turned off a specific feature: search for an option "Remove white space between pages in Print Layout View." It is on the 'back stage' view under Display.

It also looks as though your pages are unfeasibly short. Or is this my own lack of experience in Web Layout view?

Good luck.